# SQL JOIN, Replace id with value

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query that is giving me trouble, im not sure how to do this

I have to retrieve records from a TICKETS table and join it together with 2 others,, That is not the problem, i need to replace one of the values in the record for a value in another table....
For Eg:

Table tickets:

numint
user_id
type
desc
attach
priority
status
date
assignation

Table users

numint
company_id
name
email
username
password
ps
security
token
date

Table companies

numint
name

Example Record

company_name - user_name - type - title - priority - status - date - assignation

"someCompany" - "someUser" - "someTitle" - 1 - "open" - "yyy/mm/dd" - 2(user_id)

in the assignation field of the returned record i need to replace it with the correspondant value from the users table IF it's NOT 0 (zero)

This is my Query so far

```
SELECT tickets.numint, tickets.type, tickets.title, tickets.description,
       tickets.priority, tickets.status, tickets.date,
       users.name AS user_name, companies.name AS company_name,
       CASE WHEN tickets.assignation=0 THEN 'not-assigned'
       ELSE ????????? END AS assignation
       FROM tickets
       LEFT JOIN users ON tickets.user_id = users.numint
       LEFT JOIN companies ON users.company_id = companies.numint
```

i dont know how to replace that value, or if the CASE should after the joins...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to show username as assignation. use users.name in case.

```
SELECT tickets.numint, tickets.type, tickets.title, tickets.description,
       tickets.priority, tickets.status, tickets.date,
       users.name AS user_name, companies.name AS company_name,
CASE WHEN tickets.assignation=0 THEN 'not-assigned'
ELSE users1.name END AS assignation
FROM tickets
LEFT JOIN users ON tickets.user_id = users.numint
LEFT JOIN companies ON users.company_id = companies.numint
LEFT JOIN users AS users1 ON tickets.assignation = users1.numint
```

Comment: the Query returns the user.name twice ... im getting the same value in name and assignation.

Comment: the assignation field represents the ID (numint) of Another users (the support assistant) and is also stored inside the users table, i need to replace the assignation field with the name of that user's id...

Comment: For eg... the user 1010 could have assign user 555... so in the assignation field i need to show the name of the user 555...

Comment: Then you need to join user table again. See the updated answer.

Comment: but.. how do i tell the engine that users1 is the same table as users?

Comment: how do i set the aliasess?

Comment: Sorry missed the alias. Updated answer